# After installing script package, Node is not recognized

Tags: javascript

After installing the `Script` package on Atom, I cannot run JavaScript code. Here is the error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Where are you getting this error, inside the Atom terminal?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you launch Atom from the command line, so that all your environment variables are defined. If you launch it with the icon, Node might not be defined. For example, run `atom .` or `open . -a atom` in the project directory.